# How do i use the "next" url for post request?

Tags: python, python-requests

So how does python call the "next" page in a post request?

I know what i neeed to do, but not sure how to implement, all the examples in youtube use a # and not a cursor, being a semi beginner i am a bit confused

This is my code so far:

```
def main_request(headers, url1, params):

    response = requests.post(url1, headers=headers, json=params, verify=False)
    jsonData = response.json()

    has_next_key = False
    nextKey = ""

    if "next_key" in jsonData:
        next = True
        nextKey = jsonData["next"]

    while has_next_key:
        data = {"limit_count":500, "limit_size":10000,"curr_key":nextKey}
        params = {"data":json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))}

        req = requests.post(url1, headers=headers, json=params, verify=False)  ## this should do GET request for the third page and so on...
        if "next_key" in req:
            nextKey = req["next_key"]
            print(nextKey) # this returns "3321" which is the value for "next_key" in second page
        else:
            has_next_key = False
            # no next_key, stop the loop
```

This is the value is brings back at the end of each request

```
{
"data": [],
"metadata": {},
"links": [
{
"href": "https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com:443/vm/v4/integration/assets?page=0&size=2",
"rel": "first"
},
{
"href": "https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com:443/vm/v4/integration/assets?page=0&size=2",
"rel": "self"
},
{
"href": "https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com:443/vm/v4/integration/assets?page=1&size=2&cursor=1542252837:::_S:::12474375-34a7-40a3-9821-28db0b5cc90e-default-asset-10",
"rel": "next"
},
{
"href": "https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com:443/vm/v4/integration/assets?page=1097&size=2",
"rel": "last"
}
]
}
```

**according to rapid7 support, i need to use the cursor value**

Answer (score 0):

Given your `jsonData` as input, you can use this code to get the next url and assign it to `url1`:

```
for item in jsonData.get("links", []):
    if item["rel"] == "next":
        url1 = item["href"]
        break
```

This only finds the first url. If you need all urls, I'd recommend adding all urls to a list.
For examples:

```
links = [item["href"] for item in jsonData.get("links", []) if item["rel"] == "next"]
```

Comment: how do i use that for the next post request?